# Java, faster way to handle if statement than copy and pasting?

Tags: java

I have these item ids for my game: 331, 341, 366, 367, 391, 396 And I want to do this for each item:

```
if (s.getPlayer().checkInv().lookFor(item id)) {
    s.getPlayer().applyKarth(item id);
}
```

But, instead of just copy and pasting the if statement, is there a faster/smarter/compact way to do it?

Edit: Thanks for the answers, my problem is solved :-)

Quick side question if I may; What if I have other IDs, but I need them to link together with these ids?

So like this:

I have IDs 24, 26, 28, 42, 41 and 86, and they need to go with a specific item id
So like, item id 331 uses the id 24, item id 341 uses the id 26, et cetera.
Like, it's listed

How would I accomplish this?

Currently using this example, as shown in the comments:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(331, 341, 366, 367, 391, 396);
for(int itemId : list){
   if (s.getPlayer().checkInv().lookFor(itemId)) {
      s.getPlayer().applyKarth(itemId);
   }
}
```

Comment: Use a for loop to loop through a collection of player id's.

Comment: Encapsulate in a method and call that? i.e. use the language as intended.

Comment: Did you try doing in a loop ?

Comment: I don't think that `item id` is valid Java code...

Comment: I haven't tried using loops yet, I'm pretty new to Java :-) I'm currently reading about it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this -

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(331, 341, 366, 367, 391, 396);
for(int itemId : list){
   if (s.getPlayer().checkInv().lookFor(itemId )) {
      s.getPlayer().applyKarth(itemId);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this!

Comment: This worked like a charm, thanks! :-) I have a new question though, if you wouldn't mind answering? :-) (look at my edit)

Comment: Use a `Map<Integer,Integer>` to store mapping  like.. `map.put(331,24)`

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the ids:

```
List<Integer> ids = Arrays.asList(331, 341, 366, 367, 391, 396);
for (Integer id : ids) {
    Player p = s.getPlayer();
    if (p.checkInv().lookFor(id)) {
        p.applyKarth(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for( int id: new int[]{ 331, 341, 366, 367, 391, 396 } ){
    if (s.getPlayer().checkInv().lookFor( id )) {
        s.getPlayer().applyKarth( id );
        break;
    }
}
```

Adding a minor improvement with that break.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 you should use Streams:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(331, 341, 366, 367, 391, 396);
Player player = s.getPlayer();
list.stream()
    .filter(id -> player.checkInv().lookFor(id))
    .forEach(id -> player.applyKarth(id));
```